# Cropping every background photo in a PowerPoint presentation with a script?

Tags: crop, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a presentation in which I've used a different large photograph as a background photo on each slide. Each photo overlaps the slide bounds in a different configuration in order to align it as desired when viewed in slideshow. How can I efficiently crop each of these photos to the slide using a script (or other technique)?

Comment: Hello, do you want to crop images with PowerPoint software? or do you have any graphic editing software?

Comment: Of course I can crop the images manually (I have Photoshop). I'm asking how to crop them inside the PowerPoint file in one step using a script.

Comment: I think Visual Basic allows it, but (personally) think that perform batch processing in Photoshop faster and easier than in PP.

Comment: Thanks Vnovak. The issue is that the area that needs to be cropped is different for each photo and that area is defined by the area that spills over the slide boundaries on each individual slide. The photos have been scaled differently on each slide as well. Your suggestion makes me think though...